# multiple inheritance and data members

Tags: c++, oop, multiple-inheritance

I never used multiple inheritance and stumbled into a design problem I never faced..

```
class A {
     //..methods..
}

class B : public A {
    int b;
    //...methods..
}

class C : public A {
    int c1,c2;
}

class D : public B,public C {
}
```

Here's the classical diamond. The fact is that `C` is really just an `A` with two extra ints. and `D` is really just an aggregation of `B` and `C` but I feel like multiple inheritance was not designed to make things like these. Or that there may be other best practices to do this.

The reason why im trying to implement multiple inheritance is that I want to write a function like `void func(A*)` and pass it either a `A` or `D` class pointer. My ingenuous attempt is to make a simple cast:

```
void func(A* a) { // <-- I call this with a A or D pointer
   // ..do something with A members..

    if(is_the_case) { // <-- Im sure the passed "a" pointer is actually a *D
        D* d = (D*)a;
       // ..do something with the extra 2 ints provided by the C class..
    } 
}
```

Doesn't work.. Compiles fine, but I have a really strange behaviour when `if(is_the_case)` is executed, clearing that 2 extra ints `c1` and `c2`, clears also `b` (inherithed by `B`).

I remebered about the diamond problem, but here there is only one `B` (and 2 `A`) in the hierarchy, so I don't understand why `b` gets cleared as well. Just to try, I used public virtual in `B` and `C` declaration. Now every cast is a compile error unless I use a `dynamic_cast`..

Can someone make it clear what's happening behind the scenes? What is the best practice to do it, considering there are other classes like:

```
class E : public A {
    int e;
    //..methods..
}

class F : public E,public C {
}
```

That is, other classes that are just an aggregation of a class derived from `A` + two extra ints inherited by `C` and that can be passed to a funcion that takes `*A`

Thanks, did my best to be as clear as possible..

Comment: Casting a pointer type to another pointer type cannot produce an error. Can you show what you do after `D* d = (D*)a;`? What do you mean by "clearing c1, c2"? how do you do that?

Comment: c1=c2=0; ..now d.b is 0 as well.. I do not get any error.. it compiles and runs.. the problem is that b is set to 0 as well

Comment: could you check d.b value *before* assigning to d.c1 and d.c2? chances are it is already 0...

Comment: How do you deal with the ambiguous base A at the call site when you call func with a pointer to D?

Comment: yes I checked.. it was 10, after c1=c2=0, b is 0 as well. I dont call any function inside func(), so I dont face any ambiguity.. all func() does is actually insert *A in a list and if is_the_case, set c1 and c2 to 0.. just to be clear: I print b just before c1=c2=0 and right after it, and I get different values

Comment: I tought it was a design issue.. something related to my limited understanding of multiple inheritance.. maybe it is something else?

Comment: In order to call func with a D*, you somehow needed to tell the compiler which of the two A bases to point to to generate the A* argument.

Comment: ? I just call it like func(&d) and the compiler doesnt complain.. Im using gcc something on ubuntu 10.4

Comment: It should complain. Are you sure about the hierarchy?

Comment: checked.. im positive.. ok as i understand this was not expected by anyone in here.. im gonna work more on this and report here if i have news..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working because you used a C-style cast, which can be a `reinterpret_cast`, and it's my understanding that you can `reinterpret_cast` between any two pointer types, even if it doesn't make sense. You must use a `dynamic_cast` when casting up from a multiply inherited base to a more derived class. A `static_cast` would yield a compile-time error. In fact, `dynamic_cast` does both jobs at once.

```
void func(A* a) { // <-- I call this with a A or D pointer
   // ..do something with A members..

    if(D* d = dynamic_cast<D*>(a)) { // a definitely points to a D
        // and we got a guaranteed good pointer too
    } 
}
```

This is an excellent example of why C-style casts should be avoided.

Comment: but ive read somewhere dynamic_cast slows execution.. and im pretty sensitive to performance in this case.. can someone confirm?

Comment: @user815129: Who cares? You can't make your code work without it, so it's not like you could switch to some lower-performance alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about multiple inheritance [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html).

What you need to do is virtually inherit next classes :

```
class B : virtual public A {
    int b;
    //...methods..
};

class C : virtual public A {
    int c1,c2;
};
```

Comment: I already knew about that and as I said, I did it. I was just asking 1) if there is another way to implement what I want without using multiple inheritance, and 2) WHY would b get cleared if I dont use virtual inh.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're seeing this behaviour.  As noted in comments, you code as described shouldn't compile.

Is there a design issue?  Yes.  Don't explicitly make choices based on querying an object's type.  That's what virtual functions are for.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void prepare_for_list_insertion() {}
};

class B : public A
{
    int b;
};

class C : public A
{
private:
    int c1, c2;

protected:
    void clear() { c1 = c2 = 0; }
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    void prepare_for_list_insertion()
    {
        clear();
    }
};

void func(A* a)
{
    a->prepare_for_list_insertion();
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    func(&a); // calls A::prepare_for_list_insertion
    D d;
    // You need a cast to disambiguate the A base - either will do.
    func(static_cast<C*>(&d)); // calls D::prepare_for_list_insertion
    func(static_cast<B*>(&d)); // calls D::prepare_for_list_insertion
}
```

Comment: hmm.. interesting indeed.. just to know, does a static_cast<> affect runtime performance in any way?

Comment: Static_cast does the same as your C-style cast in this case; it's just more specific.  A C style cast can mean different things.  Here's a nice article about the (probable) pointer operations involved in casting around the hierarchy: http://drdobbs.com/184402074

Comment: Sadly, the links to the diagrams in that article seem to be broken...  I still think it's intelligible.

Comment: I've got to disagree with this. Virtual functions must have a constant signature across all derived classes, and it may well be that the types involved dealing with one derived class shouldn't be exposed to another, or that no derived class except one will implement them. The use cases of `dynamic_cast` are rare, but they definitely do exist and it's use is not a design issue, per se.

Comment: I decided to get rid of multiple inheritance implementing a virtual function:

struct extra_ints {
    int c1,c2;
};

class A {
    virtual extra_ints* get_ints() { return NULL; }
}

class B : public A { int b;
}

class D : public B {
    extra_ints e_i;

    extra_ints* get_ints() { return &e_i; }
}

when I need the extra ints (when is_the_case) i can just d->get_ints()->c1=123;

do you think its a bad deisgn or something?

im not kinda satisfied with this.. in this example I only have 3 classes D,E,F.. but if I had 200 Id have to add 200 identical functions.. am I missing something?